# Ember.JS view not rendering?

Tags: ember.js

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm really confused as to why this isn't working:

```
// The Javascript
App.UsersView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'user-list'
});

// The HTML
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user-list">
    Hello World
</script>
```

Nothing is displaying?

(The application view displays so it's not a problem with the way `ember.js` is loaded. Just when trying to use custom views.)

Comment: How are you trying to show the `UserView`?  Do you have other code that tries to display it?

Answer (score 1):

The only view/template that is automatically appended to the dom is application. To include UsersView on the page, try:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <pre>application view</pre>
  {{view App.UsersView}}
</script>
```

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/iluvik/1/edit

Typically the view helper is not necessary as most of the views/templates your application will get created by the ember router. Have a look at the [Ember Routing Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) for a better understanding of how to wire things up.